# Surveymonkey: Is there an API method that indicates if a survey has been completed by a user?

Tags: survey, surveymonkey

We are looking into using surveymonkey for our surveys. In the surveymonkey developer portal (https://developer.surveymonkey.com/), the site advises us to ask questions here.

Is there an API method / data point that indicates if a survey has been fully completed by a certain user?

Our (current) system rewards users (via an external API call) when the app 'knows' that the survey has been fully completed. How would I ascertain this if we were to create a web app that hooks in to the SM API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can get that information by first hitting :
https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_respondent_list

for the survey you are interested in.It will give you all the people who have responded to your survey and their status. The key you would be interested in would be "status" in the response. (Make sure to specify that you want the status in the "fields" param in the request.

Comment: Yep this is correct. Note that in order to call get_respondent_list you need a survey_id. To get a survey_id, you need to call get_survey_list, and pass an extra parameter "title" equal to the title of the survey you are looking for.